# Scaling baseline and SHAPs back to original class rate

Tags: unbalanced-classes, shapley-value

I have an imbalanced dataset (positive class rate = 1%) and have downsampled the negative class to give me a 50/50 balance in the two classes. The outputs from this model look adequate. Ignoring the challenges that comes with undersampling (e.g. loss of information), the baseline of the SHAP outputs is now close to 50% as expected.  However, I need to present the SHAP outputs including the baseline value back to the end users so that the resulting SHAP probabilities are intuitive.  Is it correct to apply a straight scaling factor of 1/50 to all the SHAP values and the baseline value to bring the SHAPs in line with the original positive class rate?  I am using lightgbm for the algorithm (in case this is relevant).